# How to call a function of month and week view in calendar list using Custom button?

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, custom, sharepoint-calendar

I have two custom button in page named as Week and Month, While clicking the month button I need to switch the calendar to month view, by same clicking the week button it need to be changed to week view. I am referring [image]

I am not sure how to achieve this.Please suggest me some idea to achieve this control

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I achieved this by

```
<html>
<body>
<input name="Week" type="button" value="Week" onclick="Test()"  />

<input name="Day" type="button" value="Day" onclick="TestDay()"  />

<input name="Month" type="button" value="Month" onclick="TestMonth()"  />
<script type="text/javascript">

function Test()
{
CoreInvoke('MoveView','week');
}

function TestDay()
{
CoreInvoke('MoveView','day');
}

function TestMonth()
{
CoreInvoke('MoveView','month');
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```